# html_entity_decode in json, textfield and div

Tags: json, html-encode

I have a function which builds a json file. It's a wordpress function, but I think that's not relevant for the question.

**The function**

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $titles[] = apply_filters('the_title', html_entity_decode($post->post_title));
}
$content = json_encode( $titles );
```

- In the json file, an ampersand becomes `&#038;`
- In the twitter's typeahead div, the ampersand becomes `&`
- In the textfield, an ampersand becomes `&#038;`

I've deleted and rebuild the file to test different things like

`html_entity_decode($post->post_title, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')`

and removing `html_entity_decode` all together but that didn't solve the problem.

All posts here suggest I should use `html_entity_decode` so I'm kind of clueless why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that it was a Wordpress related question after all... I've removed the `apply_filters` function, after which `html_entity_decode` worked as expected.